# SWIFT cell padding

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I want to fill the cells of my tableview with data from the array **gists1**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! GistCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        let gist = gists1[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: gist)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
```

the cell has a custom class

```
class GistCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelCell: UILabel!

    func configure(with gist: Gists) {
        self.labelCell.text = gist.description!
    }
}
```

This is a dump of the array data:

```
 ▿ GistShowApp.Gists
    ▿ description: Optional("helloWorldDemo")
      - some: "helloWorldDemo"
    ▿ files: 1 key/value pair
      ▿ (2 elements)
        - key: "gistfile1.txt"
        ▿ value: GistShowApp.DetailGist
          ▿ filename: Optional("gistfile1.txt")
            - some: "gistfile1.txt"
          ▿ rawUrl: Optional("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirKhuraskin/c510014b85a6bdfa302f1f3837893a7c/raw/4648e701849ee7d52fb685111a7f0e4323505a35/gistfile1.txt")
            - some: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirKhuraskin/c510014b85a6bdfa302f1f3837893a7c/raw/4648e701849ee7d52fb685111a7f0e4323505a35/gistfile1.txt"
```

I do not quite understand why an optional value is first displayed and then the **some** value itself.
this can be the reason that the cell is not filled with data?

Comment: You need to learn how do unwrap optional. That's basic stuff in Swift. For the fact that the text is no appearing, could you check if `self.labeCell` is nil ? And its `frame` in `configure(with gist:)`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this line was superfluous.

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Without it, everything works.